# Redux // React Component renders twice after action dispatching

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a strange behavior. Once I add the socket connection to the react / redux system, my main component always will be rerendered, as soon as a next Action is dispatched.

I also have the behavior, when I click again on a navigation link (dispatch the same routing action), 
the compoenent also rerenders, even I stay on the same page.

Could anyone help me here to get on track?
Thanks a lot!

**Setup**
react 0.15.x
redux
react-router v4
react-router-redux

**app.jsx and App Structure for the Container:**

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Route path="/" component={RootContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/start" component={StartPage} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**RootContainer**

```
class RootContainer extends React.Component {

...

  componentWillMount() {
    this.connectToSocket();
    this.joinChannel();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }
...

  connectToSocket() {
    this.socket = new Socket('/socket');
    this.socket.connect();
    this.socket.onOpen(() => {
      this.props.connectState();  // ACTION CALL
    });
    this.socket.onError((err) => {
      this.props.disconnectState(err); // ACTION CALL
    }
  }
```

...

reducer

Comment: The short version is that something is constantly changing your application's state. It's hard to say what exactly without seeing your reducer, but sockets would regularly be sending data (keep alive or something else). You probably only want to change state when something interesting comes across the socket.

Comment: thanks @RobDrimmie. I thought that a component only changes if the state changes, and also only re-renders parts, that need to be re-rendering?

P.S. The connected state has to stick around and is interesting, because we are building a chat. so we want notification and UI locking, when you have been disconnected.

Comment: You are correct that a component's render() function will only be called when state changes. Since yours is getting called a lot, state is changing a lot. It's hard to speculate on what is changing state without seeing your socket handling functions or the reducer. I'm speculating that whatever is handling the socket is responsible for the constantly changing state.

Answer (score 5):

Something is changing the store state. It appears your `RootContainer` component is `connect`ed to Redux, so it is likely rerendering each time. There are two main approaches to optimizing this:

- Only connect lower-level components to the state that they need. Redux's `connect` higher order component only rerenders when `mapStateToProps` produces different results. Doing this at a more granular level lower in the component tree reduces the amount of components that have to rerender on store updates.
- Extend `React.PureComponent` for any children that aren't connected to Redux, and don't need to rerender each time their parent does. By default, when a top-level component rerenders, all of its children rerender too. `PureComponent` can prevent that.

This is only general advise, it's hard to say what exactly you should do without seeing more of your app's structure.